# Accessing data from class method in an instance method objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my .m file I've declared this variable

```
static NSString* MyGlobalPassword;
```

and in the .m file I have a class method I'm calling in another class to get an NSString

```
    + (NSString *) updateMessageString: (NSString *) msgString
{
    MyGlobalPassword = msgString;

    return MyGlobalPassword;
}
```

I want to access MyGlobalPassword in an instance method of the same class

```
 - (void) Access
    {
        NSLog(@"I've retrieved it %@", MyGlobalPassword);
    }
```

Objective-C throws an unrecognized selector error when I try to do this. It doesn't want to let me access that variable in an instance method. How can I force it too?

Comment: What selector is unrecognized? What's the exact error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you get the error because your static variable isn't initialized.  It's generally not a good idea to declare variables in your .h files as they can't be included in many places that way (without additional work and headache).  You probably want to extern the declaration in your header like this:

```
extern NSString* MyGlobalPassword;
```

And declare it in your .m like this:

```
NSString* MyGlobalPassword;
```

Additionally, you usually will not want to make globals like this.  Either you should have a singleton class that gets allocated once and used in many places or you should have this be a class member.  You can also cheat and do the above, but make it static in the .m file and add class accessors to get at it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you declare a variable inside .h file, the class takes it as its instance variables or properties. So, it can be accessible only by its object. Declare that variable "MyGlobalPassword" inside the .m file. Now you can access that "global" variable inside your class methods as well as your instance methods.